# Underscore map array of object to new object with id as key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

How can I map this array of objects to a new array of objects where the object's id is the key and its value is the object?

```
var players = [{id: 2, score: 5}, {id: 3, score: 10}]

var mapped = _.map(players, function(x) { return {x.id: x}})

// desired output = [{2: {id: 2, score: 4}, {3: {id: 3, score: 10}} ]
```

I get a syntax error trying the above `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .(…)`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzge9ey8/)

Comment: I think you are looking for [reduce](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce) and not [map](https://underscorejs.org/#map) Start with an empty object and build it key by key as you iterate the array of `players`. 

If you _really_ want an array back, wrap the final object in an array. But I'm pretty sure that was not your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your JS Fiddle you were not including [underscore](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore-min.js), but this will work:

```
var mapped = _.map(players, function(player) {
  var playerObj = {};
  playerObj[player.id] = player;
  return playerObj;
})
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out a better way, I end using this method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy using ES6 functionality then you could use an arrow function which makes use of a computed property name:

```
var mapped = _.map(players, player => ({ [player.id] : player}));
```

Comment: Any reason for the down vote? Anonymous down votes with no comments  don't help anyone and I would really like to know where there is a problem so that I can learn from it and correct the answer.

Comment: Not sure either @GruffBunny, I didn't know i needed the `()` around the object, this helper me